# Can you refresh search results in Netbeans 6.9?

Tags: netbeans, ide

I was wondering if I can refresh search results in Netbeans 6.9 Search Results Window after modifying some files? Do I have to use close the window everytime and find that particular keyword again?

Are there any search results refresh shortcut? I tried F5 hahaha! It didn't work^

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of. In your search tab on the left, there is an icon that looks like a page with a wrench in the lower right corner. The tooltip for it says "Modify Criteria". Click on that and then the "Find" button.

It is not a one step refresh button, but does save you from opening another new tab.

Please note that if you use Scope: Selection, the scope might have changed between searches!